# ASP.Net Media Suite - Review

Tags: asp.net, media, suite

Does anyone have a review of ASP.Net Media Suite located on

http://www.aspnetmedia.com/

The tool seems pretty nice, but i've never heard of the company.  I'm hesitant to purchase and install something from an unknown source.

Can anyone vouch for the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, 
i have sent many emails, and never got an answer, if you ask me you are better with many other alternatives,
like there is an a amazing flash control i use 
http://www.flash-control.net/

it does everything to implement flash like XHTML valid inclusion, Option to install flash if not available, Flash Vars, etc...

then you can choose of millions of flash mp3 players, video players on net which use XML, then simply you create the XML in code and hook any special Flashvars with this control and you have a great media player.
here is a nice site i always got to for such stuff

www.flashden.net.

hope this helps.